# Запятая перед "ради чего" и "зачем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "ради чего" / "зачем" в подобных предложениях?

- Он ушёл в лес и не сказал(,) зачем?
- Ты работала здесь всю жизнь и не знаешь(,) ради чего?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В обоих случаях запятая не ставится. Наличие предлога на это не влияет.

Розенталь:
Придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного только относительного слова или **словосочетания** и стоящее после главного предложения, запятой от него не отделяется, например:
*Он ушел и не сказал куда.

Трудно сказать почему.

Знаешь что?

Я не скажу какое, я говорю — большое несчастье.

Однажды, не помню *по какому случаю*, он заявил нам...*
То же самое, если имеется несколько относительных слов, выступающих в роли однородных членов, например:
*Не знаю **почему и каким образом**, но он вдруг очутился рядом со мной.

Позвонят — расспроси **кто, по какому вопросу** и сообщи на квартиру секретарю.*
Но если при относительном слове имеется примыкающее слово или частица, то запятая ставится, например:
*Я не очень хорошо знаю, что именно.

Я не помню, что еще.*

Comment: В ваших примерах _другое_ основание отказаза от запятой (пункт "г" того же лопатинского источника): _если придаточная часть, благодаря союзам и, или, включается в ряд однородных членов_.

Comment: Это не мои примеры, а примеры Розенталя. Моё — только первая строка. У Лопатина там про другое: про соединение члена **главного** предложения с придаточным. Розенталь указывал, что это нежелательно.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая опускается в случае усечённости придаточного предложения до *единственного* союзного слова, потому в *первом* предложении её не должно быть, а во *втором* она нужна (оба предложения заканчиваются *точкой*, а не вопр. знаком).

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=384

(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации, справочник под ред. [Лопатина], § 115/в)

> Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым
> союзом или союзным словом, не ставится... если придаточная часть
> усечена до *одного* союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово
> теряет функцию придаточного предложения).

Comment: Александр, я думаю, что и во втором предложении запятая не нужна – там ведь тоже одно союзное слово ***чего*** с предлогом ***ради***.  И еще: оба предложения могут быть вопросительными.

Comment: Два книжных примера (более одного слова):

_Не ради эстетики и психологии, а ради... Я не знаю, ради чего..._
(Жизнь, А. Лосев, 1993)

_– Какого черта ты звонишь мне?
– Ты знаешь, какого черта._
(Первая смерть, Кендра Эллиот, 2021)

С вопросительным предложением: тогда вместо запятой нужен другой знак.

Comment: Примеры могут быть разные, согласен. Пунктуация в них может зависеть от структуры и интонации. *Рядом же с паланкином раджи несли, не знаю ради чего, большого попугая*... [А. Д. Салтыков. Письма из Индии (1841)]   В нашем же случае вопросительное предложение ***...и не знаешь ради чего?*** читается без паузы и никакого другого знака не нужно.

Comment: Это _единственный_ имеющийся в "корпусе" пример со "знаю ради чего", и он оказывается в  заметном меньшинстве при поиске по гугл-книгам (там есть Гиппиус, императрица Екатерина и др. -  с обособлением). Видимо, всё сложнее с _непервообразными_ предлогами; Розенталь же приводит пример только с первообразным "в" ("... не знаю в чем") и не формулирует каких-либо обобщений относительно _предлогов_ в этой конструкции.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ oleedd абсолютно верен,** но меня удивила дискуссия по этому вопросу и наличие разных мнений. Поэтому я добавлю свой ответ.

*Он ушёл в лес и не сказал(,) зачем?*

*Ты работала здесь всю жизнь и не знаешь(,) ради чего?*

1. По правилу Розенталя запятая в этих случаях обычно не ставится, но возможны исключения по условиям контекста. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137  пункт 4(3).
2. У Розенталя даны два примера, которые поясняют **значение контекста.** Но нужно понимать, что контекст в общем случае – это влияние **интонационной структуры** предложения.

**Вариант 1. Запятая не ставится.** Он ушёл и не сказал кудА. Не знаю почему и каким Образом, но письмо вдруг исчезло. Позвонят — расспроси кто и зачЕм.

Запятая не ставится, так как ударение падает на конец фразы, в том числе если союзные слова соединены союзом И.

**Вариант 2. Запятая  ставится.** *Что же надо делать? НаучИте, чтО.  Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понЯть — чтО*? (А. Т.)

Запятая ставится,  если в предложении **можно сделать два ударения.** Тогда союзное слово будет выделено логически, и все это видно по структуре предложения (по контексту).

3. Рассмотрим интонационную структуру заданных предложений.

(1) Он ушёл в лес и не сказал зачЕм? (2) Ты работала здесь всю жизнь и не знаешь ради чегО?

В этих предложениях мы видим **однородные сказуемые,**  связанные одиночным союзом И, причем союзное слово  относится к одному из них. При такой структуре  не имеет смысла нарушать целостность этого однородного члена, да и прочтение предложения при наличии обособления затруднительно.

**Вывод:** Запятые в этих предложениях однозначно **не ставятся.**